# Normalization - How do I properly reference a list from one table in multiple fields in another table?

Tags: ms-access, rdbms, database-normalization

I'm pretty sure this is a basic question, but I'll be darned if I can find an example that helps me understand the proper way to do what I need to do.

In MS Access 365 I am creating a maintenance tracking database.  I have a table with basic employee information.  Employees can both perform maintenance tasks and verify maintenance tasks.  I can set up a one to many reference using the Employee ID PK as a FK in my task log table for who performed the task.  Obviously, I can't set up another one to many relationship to a field of who verified the task.

I already have the task details in a separate table which is referenced by the task log table.  Am I just being stubborn in not splitting my task log table into task performed and task verified?  Is there another way to normalize this data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously, I can't set up another one to many relationship to a field of who verified the task.

Yes, you totally can.

When you drag&drop the 2nd relation, Access will ask if you want to edit the existing relation or create a new one.

It will display like this, but it is actually 2 one-to-many relations from User to Log.

[image: Two FK relations]

Comment: Hmm...I said "obviously" because I tried it and it didn't work! Let me investigate that option again...

Comment: *sigh* It absolutely works.  I had a mismatched field type is why it didn't work the first time and I didn't read the error message closely enough.  Thanks!  As a side benefit, I learned a lot about supertype and subtype arrangements that I ended up using to design a different portion of the database.  So it wasn't a total waste of time.

Comment: I don't remember unaccepting anything.  That's weird.  Thanks for posting that so I can fix it.